# No file or variants found for asset: assets/credentials.json error when trying to load in JSON credentials

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dialogflow-es

I am trying to pass in some json credentials to my app but get the below error:

```
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
No file or variants found for asset: assets/credentials.json.
```

Any ideas? In there are credentials in the credentials.json file, so I am unsure why that error is being thrown.

Comment: The error is saying that it can't find the file 'credentials.json' in folder '<your project folder >/assets'. Are you sure it is there?

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: make sure `assets` folder is in the same level with `lib` folder, not under `lib` forlder

[image]

Step 2: make sure `pubspec.yaml` file has correct indent

[image]

Step 3: make sure you have put file `credentials.json` under `assets` folder

Comment: I have tried again and still getting the same error. I have double checked, and formatting in ymal file is correct.  `uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/credentials.json`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure on pubspec.yaml than all your assets definitions for folders ends with /.

Example:
assets:
- assets/